# How do I wrap the same block of code in a loop (or apply function)

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I want to wrap in a loop a block of code that performs the same operations over imported DataFrames from different csv files. Consider an example:
I import

```
apples=pd.read_csv("path\dataset_1.csv")
oranges=pd.read_csv("path\dataset_2.csv")
```

The structure, the format and column names of imported DataFrames are totally the same.
Then I perform operations on the first set. For example

```
apples_1 = apples [["column A", "column B"]]
apples_1. columns= ["bad", "good"]
apples_2 = apples [["column C", "column D"]]
apples_2. columns = [ "bad", "good"]
apples_3=pd.concat([apples_1,apples_2],axis=0)
```

Then, however I must perform absolutely the same operations over the second data frame – oranges. I remind that the second DataFrame has same column names as the first one and will have the same renamed columns after the operation.

```
 oranges_1 = oranges [["column A", "column B"]]
 oranges_1. columns= ["bad", "good"]
 oranges_2 = oranges [["column C", "column D"]]
 oranges_2. columns = [ "bad", "good"]
 oranges_3=pd.concat([oranges_1,oranges_2],axis=0)
```

It would not be very Pythonic if I have 10 DataFrames and have to perform the same operations by writing same code over and over; so I was wondering if there is an elegant way to do this with a loop maybe, or apply a function.Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,11):
    df = pd.read_csv("path\dataset_{0}.csv".format(i))
    adf=pd.concat([df[["column A", "column B"]],df[["column C", "column D"]]],axis=0)
    adf.columns = [ "bad", "good", "bad", "good"]
    # do operations on adf
```

Loop over each csv, read it into a df and operate on it. As long as all the csv files have the same column names (as mentioned in the question) it should work.

Comment: Could you please explain the "dataset_{0}" term in the file-path. My original csv file names are: dataset_2018-2019 , dataset_2017-2018 etc. not like in the example I gave. Sorry for the confusion. Now I am struggling to accommodate your solution with my original file names. Other than that I think the answer provided will work.

Comment: why dont you hardcode all the file names in a list and use it like

`files = [ 'path\dataset_2018-2019.csv', 'path\dataset_2017-2018.csv']
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    adf=pd.concat([df[["column A", "column B"]],df[["column C", "column D"]]],axis=0)
    adf.columns = [ "bad", "good", "bad", "good"]`